# Is a bit string pseudorandom if it starts with predictable bits?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, terminology

Assume we have $k = n + m$ bits string $S$ where the first $n$ bits are predictable, and the last $m$ bits are pseudorandom (the HMAC of the first $n$ bits + IV). Can we say $S$ is a pseudorandom number?

What can we call S exactly?

Comment: What's IV.....?

Comment: @PaulUszak IV is a random number

Comment: Ah! So to be clear, $m = \operatorname{HMAC}(n||IV)$? And what's $|IV|$ then?

Answer (score 1):

No, first of all, you've defined it to be a bit string. A bit string is not a number although you can of course *interpret* it as a specific number.

Furthermore, it is not pseudo-random if we assume that the number is between 0 and the maximum value for S, as it clearly is either in a range, or it ends with a lower end bits set to a specific value.

Now if we assume big endian then you can however consider $S$ pseudo random *in the range* $\Big[N \cdot 2^m, (N + 1) \cdot 2^m \Big)$ where $N$ is the big endian value of the first $n$ bits of $S$.

I don't know what we can call $S$, it's a constructed bit string. With the HMAC it could be some kind of token, but that's speculating on a specific use case for it.